# Media Upload File Sizes

Tags: file, file-upload, media

I'm building a website that allows uploads of photo's, audio and video but I obviously don't want to overload the server so I'm thinking of limiting the files sizes. So I want to know a general acceptable file size for each file based on:

> Photo: An Acceptable Limit
>
> Audio: Limited to 1 Minute
>
> Video: Limited to 1 Minute

I know that all file's are different sizes based on compression, etc but I'm talking about a general acceptable figure here for each. Any help would be of huge help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use below figures(Max_Limit) for your application:

```
   Photo: 2 MB
   Audio: 10 MB
   Vedio: 100 MB
```